# Cloudfront distribution not respecting cache-control header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

My Cloudfront distribution is aggressively caching my `index.html` file on the initial `GET` request. While I use versioned file names for all other files, I want the freshest `index.html` on every request. The origin is an S3 bucket and I upload my file using the `--cache-control` flag:

`aws s3 cp index.html s3://buck/index.html --cache-control "max-age=0"`

When the above was not working, I tried:

`aws s3 cp index.html s3://buck/index.html --cache-control "no-store"`

**I have verified that the headers are set on the S3 object:**

```
> aws s3api head-object --bucket buck --key index.html
```

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "Tue, 31 Mar 2020 14:10:40 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 3265,
    "ETag": "",
    "CacheControl": "no-store",
    "ContentType": "text/html",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

What smells is that *after* I change the cache control to `no-store`, **the response headers in the browser still show `cache-control: max-age=0`**. I also see `x-cache: Miss from cloudfront` but I guess that would be expected? Opening the site in a private window shows the correct response header.

My `CacheBehaviors` for the distribution are:

```
{
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Items": [
        {
            "PathPattern": "index.html",
            "TargetOriginId": "hostingS3Bucket",
            "ForwardedValues": {
                "QueryString": false,
                "Cookies": {
                    "Forward": "none"
                },
                "Headers": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                }
            },
            "TrustedSigners": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
            "MinTTL": 0,
            "AllowedMethods": {
                "Quantity": 2,
                "Items": [
                    "HEAD",
                    "GET"
                ],
                "CachedMethods": {
                    "Quantity": 2,
                    "Items": [
                        "HEAD",
                        "GET"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "SmoothStreaming": false,
            "DefaultTTL": 0,
            "MaxTTL": 0,
            "Compress": true,
            "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "FieldLevelEncryptionId": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Going by the [aws cloudfront docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) it seems like **CloudFront and browsers should respect the headers when origin adds `Cache-Control: no-store`**. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Do I have to invalidate the cache? I would like to understand this behavior so I can update my site in a predictable way.

Comment: I even manually invalidated the cache for `/index.html` and still no luck :(